# git: list all files in HEAD that have more than one author

Tags: bash, git

I can check all authors of a file with this command:

```
git shortlog -n -s -- somefile.txt
```

How can I list all files in HEAD that have more than one author? It can occur e.g. when a file was removed and then readded by someone who is not the original author.

Comment: The `bash` tag should be removed, since the question is only about git.

Comment: @ShaneBishop: I'm not sure you can accomplish this without bash.

Comment: @user1876484 Bash is more or less just a interpreter that calls the actual executable git. Not sure if the tag should be removed, though.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: one probably needs to do it in two steps - get all files in HEAD and then iterate through all of them looking for those with more than one author. That's why bash. I doubt it can be a git only one-liner.